# Incorrect comma usage

Tags: commas

If both predicates pertain to the same subject, do I need to use an 'and' to separate them?

Example:  Mrs. Hayes takes her son by the arm, tries to pull him from us, but Elijah pries his bicep from her grip and steps away.

Is that right? Or must I say

Mrs. Hayes takes her son by the arm and tries to pull him from us, but Elijah pries his bicep from her grip and steps away.

Comment: In a narrative, it's the author's call.  The second version is less stylized; the syntax calls less attention to itself.  The jerky syntax of the first might be considered mimetic of the little scuffle between Mrs. Hayes and her son.

Answer (score 1):

I think the second one is the correct one since the comma in the first one gives the idea that you are going to continue mentioning more actions, the "and" should be used before the last activity in spite of having the same subject.

Comment: ... CAPS LOCK...